# Will my citizens stop loving the king if I only give them wine for a day?

Tags: civilization-5

In Civilization 5, cities will occasionally demand a luxury resource your empire does not have, such as **Wine**. If you connect this luxury resource to your empire, the city will enter into a **We Love the King Day**, which gives a bonus to population growth for, not a single day, but rather 20 turns or so.

Do I lose the population growth bonus if I lose access to Wine before the 20 turns is up?

Maybe they only needed the Wine for a single day to experience growth for the next <strike>9 months</strike> 20 turns?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you only need to connect the luxury resource once to enjoy the full 20-turn benefit.